# Create two different VMs using an ARM template in the same resource group

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

so I'm pretty new to the whole ARM templates or the IaC concept as a whole. My first project was to create a customized VM deployment with its own NSG rules, script and so on. It was not an issue since the [github ARM template sample page](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates) is a huge help. Also the documentation is clear on that.

The next project is creating two different VMs in the same RG. I cannot use copy since the VMs have to be named differently (not a problem, since I can use an array), have different sizes (maybe an array, too? idk) and NSG rules (array?). They will share the same vnet though, since they need to talk to each other on a local connection (for security reasons).

Does anyone have any experience to share with this? Maybe using nested templates would suffice?

Anyway, any tips you guys give me, I'll gladly test them and share .

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create 2 VM's that are the same except for the name, then you should use Virtual Machine Scale Sets, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/overview

For the name of the VM see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-instance-ids

Comment: They have to be different and individual. That's the catch. I currently use VMSS for hosting my kubernetes installation and that behaviour would not work for the use case I need.

Comment: Then I would use a single ARM template with a parameter file for each VM https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-tutorial-use-parameter-file?tabs=azure-powershell

Comment: That would also be my take on this, just needed it confirmed. Thanks. I will gladly share my experience when done.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Copy-Loops inside one ARM template: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/copy-resources

You provide things like the name and the SKUs in an array/map and iterate over those.

Comment: Thanks. That's the plan for now. I will share my experience when done.